# not enough value to unpack in BERT

Tags: python, tensorflow, deep-learning, bert-language-model

I am training a FinBERT model (trained on Finance corpus), this is my code for training process:

```
for epoch in range(EPOCHS):
    
    # Show details 
    print(f"Epoch {epoch + 1}/{EPOCHS}")
    print("-" * 10)
    
    train_acc, train_loss = train_epoch(
        model,
        train_data_loader,
        loss_fn,
        optimizer,
        device,
        scheduler,
        len(train) # ***Notification says error comes from this line***
    )
    
    print(f"Train loss {train_loss} accuracy {train_acc}")
```

This is the function for that phase:

```
def train_epoch(model, data_loader, loss_fn, optimizer, device, scheduler, n_examples):
    model = model.train()
    losses = []
    correct_predictions = 0  
    for d in data_loader:
        input_ids = d["input_ids"].to(device)
        attention_mask = d["attention_mask"].to(device)
        targets = d["sentiments"].to(device)
        outputs = model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
        
        _, preds = torch.max(outputs, dim=1)
        loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
        correct_predictions += torch.sum(preds == targets)
        losses.append(loss.item())
        
        # Backward prop
        loss.backward()
        
        # Gradient Descent
        nn.utils.clip_grad_norm_(model.parameters(), max_norm=1.0)
        optimizer.step()
        scheduler.step()
        optimizer.zero_grad()
    
    return correct_predictions.double() / n_examples, np.mean(losses)
```

However, I got this error: `ValueError: not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)`  The error popped up in these lines of the below code: `attention_mask=attention_mask` and `len(train)` as I noted in the last and first code blocks. According to what I have searched, I understand this error as: the `attention_mask` should be 2d tensor, not 1d tensor and should look like this:

```
tensor([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1]], device='cuda:0')
```

not 1d tensor like this:

```
tensor([1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1,
         1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], device='cuda:0')
```

and I have checked, the `attention_mask` indeed  is 2d tensor like in former case.
So I am confused what might be the cause of this error? and what should be fixed then? Below is the code block with a line causing the error (together with the first code block). Many thanks for your help

```
 class SentimentClassifier(nn.Module):
    
    # Constructor class 
    def __init__(self, n_classes):
        super(SentimentClassifier, self).__init__()
        self.finbert = finbert
        self.drop = nn.Dropout(p=0.3)
        self.out = nn.Linear(self.finbert.config.hidden_size, n_classes)
    
    # Forward propagaion class
    def forward(self, input_ids, attention_mask):
        _, pooled_output = self.finbert(
          input_ids=input_ids,
          attention_mask=attention_mask ***Notification says error comes from this line***
        )
        #  Add a dropout layer 
        output = self.drop(pooled_output)
        return self.out(output)
```

Comment: You need to include full tracebacks, errors without context are meaningless, specially if you don't say in which line the error happens.

Comment: [closed] I have done fixing the error

Answer (score 0):

Isn't your error in this line?

```
outputs = model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
```

Because bert model outputs a tuple, so try this:

```
_, outputs = model(
            input_ids=input_ids,
            attention_mask=attention_mask
        )
loss = loss_fn(outputs, targets)
```